# SQL Alchemy KeyError

Tags: python, keyerror

I am trying to run this code and factor it into the project I'm presently working on byt I got this error instead. I will really appreciate suggestions to resolve this.

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/xx/r0d38pls0fvcl3w6zvds4d600000gn/T/ipykernel_93554/2437772952.py in \<module\>
72     csvreader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, quotechar='"')
73
\---\> 74     listings = \[prepare_listing(row) for row in csvreader\]
75
76     session = Session()

/var/folders/xx/r0d38pls0fvcl3w6zvds4d600000gn/T/ipykernel_93554/2437772952.py in \<listcomp\>(.0)
72     csvreader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, quotechar='"')
73
\---\> 74     listings = \[prepare_listing(row) for row in csvreader\]
75
76     session = Session()

/var/folders/xx/r0d38pls0fvcl3w6zvds4d600000gn/T/ipykernel_93554/2437772952.py in prepare_listing(row)
65     """Takes a row from CSV file and returns a Listing object from it."""
66
\---\> 67     row\["last_review"\] = parse_none(row\["last_review"\])
68     return Listing(\*\*row)
69

KeyError: 'last_review'
```

```
"""Move data to a database with SQLAlchemy

Script demonstrating how to move data from a CSV file to a database
using SQLAlchemy.

"""

import csv

from dateutil.parser import parse
from sqlalchemy import Column, Date, Float, Integer, String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///ab_nyc.sqlite3", echo=True)

Base = declarative_base()

class Listing(Base):
"""SQLAlchemy mapped class. Maps a Listing object to the corresponding
database table."""

    __tablename__ = "listings_sqlalchemy"
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(200))
    
    host_id = Column(Integer)
    host_name = Column(String(50))
    
    neighbourhood_group = Column(String(20))
    neighbourhood = Column(String(20))
    
    latitude = Column(Float)
    longitude = Column(Float)
    
    room_type = Column(String(20))
    price = Column(Integer)
    minimum_nights = Column(Integer)
    
    number_of_reviews = Column(Integer)
    last_review = Column(Date, nullable=True)
    reviews_per_month = Column(Integer)
    calculated_host_listings_count = Column(Integer)
    availability_365 = Column(Integer)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

def parse_none(dt):
"""Trys to parse a string date and returns None if unable to."""

    try:
        return parse(dt)
    except:
        return None

def prepare_listing(row):
"""Takes a row from CSV file and returns a Listing object from it."""

    row["last_review"] = parse_none(row["last_review"])
    return Listing(**row)

with open("AB_NYC_2019.csv", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as csv_file:
csvreader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, quotechar='"')

    listings = [prepare_listing(row) for row in csvreader]
    
    session = Session()
    session.add_all(listings)
    session.commit()
```

Comment: What does `AB_NYC_2019.csv` look like? Does your first row actually contain a column named `last_review`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, it has a column called last_review. I triple-checked to ensure that the name in the dataset is correct, but the error is still there. I'm not so sure how to proceed with this.

Comment: The format of the input csv file might not correspond to the default format of the csv reader. Can you show an example of what the csv file looks like?

Comment: These are the first few lines of the csv file:
listing_id,name,host_id,host_name,neighbourhood_group,neighbourhood,latitude,longitude,room_type,price,minimum_nights,number_of_reviews,last_review,reviews_per_month,calculated_host_listings_count,availability_365
`2539,Clean & quiet apt home by the park,2787,John,Brooklyn,Kensington,40.64749,-73.97237,Private room,149,1,9,2018-10-19,0.21,6,365
2595,Skylit Midtown Castle,2845,Jennifer,Manhattan,Midtown,40.75362,-73.98377,Entire home/apt,225,1,45,2019-05-21,0.38,2,355`